# MYSQL ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails Another issue

Tags: mysql

I just posted another question mere minutes ago and solved the issue now I have another one and I have no idea where I have went wrong with this one.

```
mysql> describe customers;

+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| states_id | tinyint(3)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into customers (name, email, states_id) values('Thomas', 't@email.com', 2);
    ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`crm`.`customers`, CONSTRAINT `customers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`states_id`) REFERENCES `states` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

mysql> insert into customers (name, email, states_id) values('Thomas', 't@email.com', 2);
    ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`crm`.`customers`, CONSTRAINT `customers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`states_id`) REFERENCES `states` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

mysql> describe states
    -> ;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | tinyint(3)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the result of

```
SELECT * FROM states;
```

I would wager you don't have an entry with ID 2 in that table.  The referenced ID must exist in that table before you can insert a related entry in the other table.

Comment: Yep it's amazing what I learn I dropped the table earlier and forgot to re-add the state data! Thank. I think that is enough for me tonight!

Comment: I'm glad to help!  Please consider marking this as the selected answer.